# Android CharSequence[] Array Doesn't work

Tags: android, arraylist, charsequence

I've got some Error about that.This Dialog shows nothing.What's wrong?

```
             ArrayList<String> WikiOnBellek = new ArrayList<String>();
             WikiOnBellek.add("One");
             WikiOnBellek.add("Two");
             WikiOnBellek.add("Three");
             final CharSequence[] WikiSorguEkraniCharSeq = WikiOnBellek.toArray(new CharSequence[WikiOnBellek.size()]);
             AlertDialog.Builder Wikidialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
             Wikidialog.setMessage("Wikipedia Arama Sonuçları::");
             Wikidialog.setItems(WikiSorguEkraniCharSeq, new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),WikiSorguEkraniCharSeq[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).sho
                 }
             });
             Wikidialog.create();
             Wikidialog.show();

         }
```

Comment: Wow. Such info!

Comment: It's not big deal.Just Native java syntax.There is no recursive or void function thing in there.

Comment: What error did you get? Stack trace please, i am not an wizard.

Comment: You can compile it even with notepad.If you know the answer,that will be an honour to hear otherwise please do not interrupt stackoverflow community.Thanks.

Comment: Is this an compile error or runtime error?

Comment: It simply shows nothing.As you can see it's AlertDialog-Android class.Just shows "Wikipedia Arama Sonuçları::"...It has to show "One,Two,Three" as listview in Dialog.

Comment: It has no error.Even without "Warning"s.It simply shows nothing.I am sure that my code is same with that.If you can compile it,you would see that.Thanks a alot.

Comment: I have no android libraries, and even android device near. It just says about MainActivity and AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
Wikidialog.setMessage("Wikipedia Arama Sonuçları::");
```

to

```
Wikidialog.setTitle("Wikipedia Arama Sonuçları::");
```